# ssl_upgrade_failure with makecert.exe-created certificate

Tags: ssl, erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to configure SSL for connections to my RabbitMQ broker. I think that my problem is related specifically to Erlang's SSL implementation. I was able to get it working with a certificate/key pair created directly with OpenSSL; however, when I convert a certificate made with makecert.exe (and signed with an internal test CA, also created with makecert.exe) to PEM format and try to use that, the client fails to connect and the server logs an ssl_upgrade_failure. It seems that there is something about my certificate that Erlang's SSL implementation doesn't like.

I am using Erlang R16B and the makecert.exe bundled with the Windows 7 SDK.

Here is my certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is the relevant part of the log from RabbitMQ:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 28-Mar-2013::20:46:52 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.301.0> (192.168.51.234:50804 -> 192.168.51.153:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Mar-2013::20:46:52 ===
** State machine <0.302.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {tcp,#Port<0.15153>,
                            <<22,3,0,0,53,1,0,0,49,3,0,81,84,228,150,220,41,
                              203,120,104,165,175,147,215,108,167,136,54,238,
                              178,50,70,122,181,212,166,114,251,121,27,202,52,
                              143,0,0,10,0,5,0,10,0,19,0,4,0,255,1,0>>}
** When State == hello
**      Data  == {state,server,
                     {#Ref<0.0.0.1972>,<0.301.0>},
                     gen_tcp,tcp,tcp_closed,tcp_error,"localhost",5671,
                     #Port<0.15153>,
                     {ssl_options,[],verify_none,
                         {#Fun<ssl.1.131723950>,[]},
                         false,false,undefined,1,
                         <<"C:/Users/ScottB/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/lkcloudstaging_cer.pem">>,
                         undefined,
                         <<"C:/Users/ScottB/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/server/key.pem">>,
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,<<>>,undefined,
                         undefined,
                         [<<0,107>>,
                          <<0,106>>,
                          <<0,61>>,
                          <<0,103>>,
                          <<0,64>>,
                          <<0,60>>,
                          <<0,57>>,
                          <<0,56>>,
                          <<0,53>>,
                          <<0,22>>,
                          <<0,19>>,
                          <<0,10>>,
                          <<0,51>>,
                          <<0,50>>,
                          <<0,47>>,
                          <<0,5>>,
                          <<0,4>>,
                          <<0,21>>,
                          <<0,9>>],
                         #Fun<ssl.0.131723950>,true,268435456,false,undefined,
                         undefined,false,undefined,undefined},
                     {socket_options,binary,0,0,0,false},
                     {connection_states,
                         {connection_state,
                             {security_parameters,
                                 <<0,0>>,
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined},
                             undefined,undefined,undefined,0,undefined,
                             undefined,undefined},
                         {connection_state,
                             {security_parameters,undefined,0,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 <<81,84,228,124,31,218,166,3,48,108,125,182,
                                   121,180,129,153,59,55,16,200,98,117,189,183,
                                   170,169,208,189,111,61,67,162>>,
                                 undefined},
                             undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                             undefined,undefined,undefined},
                         {connection_state,
                             {security_parameters,
                                 <<0,0>>,
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined},
                             undefined,undefined,undefined,0,undefined,
                             undefined,undefined},
                         {connection_state,
                             {security_parameters,undefined,0,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 undefined,undefined,undefined,
                                 <<81,84,228,124,31,218,166,3,48,108,125,182,
                                   121,180,129,153,59,55,16,200,98,117,189,183,
                                   170,169,208,189,111,61,67,162>>,
                                 undefined},
                             undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                             undefined,undefined,undefined}},
                     [],<<>>,<<>>,
                     {[],[]},
                     [],311374,
                     {session,undefined,undefined,
                         <<48,130,3,79,48,130,2,59,160,3,2,1,2,2,16,98,235,177,
                           236,230,246,4,190,79,82,112,203,129,63,226,129,48,9,
                           6,5,43,14,3,2,29,5,0,48,40,49,38,48,36,6,3,85,4,3,
                           19,29,69,108,108,107,97,121,32,83,116,97,103,105,
                           110,103,32,82,111,111,116,32,65,117,116,104,111,114,
                           105,116,121,48,30,23,13,49,50,48,56,49,53,49,53,49,
                           51,51,55,90,23,13,51,57,49,50,51,49,50,51,53,57,53,
                           57,90,48,51,49,49,48,47,6,3,85,4,3,30,40,0,42,0,46,
                           0,108,0,107,0,99,0,108,0,111,0,117,0,100,0,115,0,
                           116,0,97,0,103,0,105,0,110,0,103,0,46,0,99,0,111,0,
                           109,48,130,1,34,48,13,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,1,
                           1,5,0,3,130,1,15,0,48,130,1,10,2,130,1,1,0,216,107,
                           203,59,146,53,176,206,81,90,131,236,230,242,255,63,
                           137,54,50,2,25,233,165,164,253,42,153,192,25,240,
                           150,196,237,200,191,151,151,174,5,140,8,200,172,191,
                           46,248,216,97,94,153,241,153,76,40,134,243,152,72,
                           10,196,96,166,73,152,211,114,13,60,65,124,70,236,37,
                           233,37,249,108,255,92,156,191,194,222,237,60,244,
                           122,157,166,204,25,197,134,67,130,52,52,51,219,48,
                           14,136,143,202,234,12,1,208,61,173,191,115,190,143,
                           124,173,156,193,60,195,228,232,229,234,115,101,41,
                           223,24,116,72,186,212,56,140,46,235,87,63,19,214,
                           130,226,197,140,167,67,127,109,27,162,249,0,185,174,
                           230,237,67,101,52,88,155,54,136,108,93,122,115,167,
                           114,214,111,14,10,160,47,67,114,231,202,70,106,174,
                           233,35,141,162,195,148,148,250,101,181,20,93,166,94,
                           25,45,154,189,255,25,51,71,254,30,90,221,13,31,136,
                           20,47,194,198,42,113,204,118,186,145,43,92,251,87,
                           89,86,10,163,141,62,234,151,217,196,67,255,3,105,
                           121,133,224,46,248,244,66,219,181,99,165,72,31,196,
                           151,5,2,3,1,0,1,163,114,48,112,48,19,6,3,85,29,37,4,
                           12,48,10,6,8,43,6,1,5,5,7,3,1,48,89,6,3,85,29,1,4,
                           82,48,80,128,16,199,202,242,24,178,198,39,100,43,
                           232,218,214,25,128,214,79,161,42,48,40,49,38,48,36,
                           6,3,85,4,3,19,29,69,108,108,107,97,121,32,83,116,97,
                           103,105,110,103,32,82,111,111,116,32,65,117,116,104,
                           111,114,105,116,121,130,16,46,237,149,227,229,242,
                           192,187,64,151,189,228,119,196,120,180,48,9,6,5,43,
                           14,3,2,29,5,0,3,130,1,1,0,40,128,61,39,14,71,240,
                           213,139,6,56,100,53,82,197,225,133,169,236,225,234,
                           230,214,183,134,170,173,137,109,135,163,131,88,93,
                           83,210,229,35,127,245,74,146,195,237,94,80,49,3,61,
                           69,236,129,230,127,205,21,0,99,216,215,198,102,31,
                           210,111,157,92,250,236,247,70,112,168,186,68,193,
                           216,190,144,83,239,219,219,191,79,254,245,53,241,
                           116,137,118,250,166,159,185,86,249,114,73,146,150,
                           173,105,34,201,103,149,155,51,183,125,169,194,180,
                           152,14,242,226,133,244,75,74,219,213,51,50,173,80,
                           100,108,186,15,222,81,235,130,64,16,26,148,1,230,
                           184,216,123,237,176,186,6,122,118,100,200,63,236,
                           113,27,209,186,151,65,45,102,58,234,98,55,118,37,
                           165,239,242,175,122,83,239,236,75,207,44,215,224,
                           214,59,27,38,21,59,101,79,159,61,164,188,214,235,78,
                           196,207,88,238,242,212,212,28,222,208,219,68,140,16,
                           120,42,169,97,216,173,7,37,77,113,47,243,128,224,
                           234,114,145,245,54,42,72,124,191,201,76,193,111,3,
                           147,180,142,88,41,73,0,219,71,24,144,16,184,201,246,
                           107>>,
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,new,63531722812},
                     323665,ssl_session_cache,undefined,undefined,false,
                     undefined,undefined,undefined,
                     {'RSAPrivateKey','two-prime',
                         25091000490399564416382733665912293706281236323287507449391018333858706088067104372951637210440828548699801793107621328582247328739957168356535343760898421117596223923057958675108280840952652110424468556362893842108742460936250265912296002218912760264533284800177616747391132407486580757942725318853670784742540298023139943942002078742079335138046822007139070167779479715409389988021492873379536675527198388004784204705449619014967663111341423672277165259908002197645143645833929707716094821495848245665580802072300300901995696081299311434728567907957618159230597695337971845318310069905698028328520007565703331606819,
                         65537,
                         12532291835951284642352753464759952731760837234028003552929880741268762456120795803045590924921343389430997938501684187097537025786559622030041471881063352256944852432936802405831735737793065202597533511207149656340503466992496089298764016305810310122514496309703131156584850210212028846765905833153120519214366483351036620512028360903366902227866159233021509892771286294064778569099266243884082209785268720465970929381008430443130075496396131177443808450873061131440124680376808011317874020764946935204300278562787258089499308485762628408971801392792765876969493808892573747399158232707154902628249712310347508330481,
                         164613524625768478096728511491146234379950805547018160443402940694931123301226530314268605486708880647658162742710176890755691202467149416112553065729831746391569481381229328262217225008710581122456985360175690217141752754366597025760074826970126144030433840076718674219450293036228318089528491377991378917023,
                         152423687831490839453627602007609954938806264385151113997291723876694061058672531571680491904693205860873313947735180318401018227463103944680073963443527347105243646402511993135691316201430837009543216841366727950952917475175355759283610454988240555587842851002909990207473661609226206434152468235025307200253,
                         103984547751379971996375538203182369609466154978729646218112491292391375460388439026510307132524542623745369476562226118076733144497574174552444945117251391868174999766567175194585209852993108440859312097378784492720927449807326399887717438420071901928924585277569562140638458907286206884483421800776127924467,
                         39507777060187907438527428403852332339678380351718296130002815409515266417499584872791499702229633458331247753638059539934359165508273901891762155988452310073344428665326017782260225343145179490686339388197454990354108505894437772295812911773276810317388444847741459078907412450309375905167279214922484907925,
                         140777917719684893441642072243040594921813463059778562021367548768326948139714681618402000290527139618053328133891840461484222782830228667641262369743730585486629970714763524415800836168519782394433537656246543908266747427470739521793087643652694808980372432733634387874662999415574210646072641560865328049441,
                         asn1_NOVALUE},
                     {'DHParameter',
                         179769313486231590770839156793787453197860296048756011706444423684197180216158519368947833795864925541502180565485980503646440548199239100050792877003355816639229553136239076508735759914822574862575007425302077447712589550957937778424442426617334727629299387668709205606050270810842907692932019128194467627007,
                         2,asn1_NOVALUE},
                     undefined,undefined,315471,#Ref<0.0.0.1974>,undefined,
                     <<>>,true,
                     {false,first},
                     {<0.301.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.1971>},
                     #Ref<0.0.0.1980>,
                     {[],[]},
                     false,true,false,undefined}
** Reason for termination = 
** {{badmatch,
        {error,
            {asn1,
                {'Type not compatible with table constraint',
                    {{component,'Type'},
                     {value,{5,<<>>}},
                     {unique_name_and_value,id,{1,3,14,3,2,29}}}}}}},
    [{public_key,pkix_decode_cert,2,[{file,"public_key.erl"},{line,218}]},
     {ssl_cipher,filter,2,[{file,"ssl_cipher.erl"},{line,484}]},
     {ssl_handshake,select_session,8,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,654}]},
     {ssl_handshake,hello,4,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,178}]},
     {ssl_connection,hello,2,[{file,"ssl_connection.erl"},{line,413}]},
     {ssl_connection,next_state,4,[{file,"ssl_connection.erl"},{line,2001}]},
     {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7,[{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,494}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Mar-2013::20:46:52 ===
error on AMQP connection <0.301.0>: {ssl_upgrade_failure,
                                     {{{badmatch,
                                        {error,
                                         {asn1,
                                          {'Type not compatible with table constraint',
                                           {{component,'Type'},
                                            {value,{5,<<>>}},
                                            {unique_name_and_value,id,
                                             {1,3,14,3,2,29}}}}}}},
                                       [{public_key,pkix_decode_cert,2,
                                         [{file,"public_key.erl"},{line,218}]},
                                        {ssl_cipher,filter,2,
                                         [{file,"ssl_cipher.erl"},{line,484}]},
                                        {ssl_handshake,select_session,8,
                                         [{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,654}]},
                                        {ssl_handshake,hello,4,
                                         [{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,178}]},
                                        {ssl_connection,hello,2,
                                         [{file,"ssl_connection.erl"},
                                          {line,413}]},
                                        {ssl_connection,next_state,4,
                                         [{file,"ssl_connection.erl"},
                                          {line,2001}]},
                                        {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7,
                                         [{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,494}]},
                                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
                                      {gen_fsm,sync_send_all_state_event,
                                       [<0.302.0>,{start,5000},infinity]}}}
```

Note that this certificate/key pair was created for testing purposes only, but I am concerned that our production certificate/key pair will fail in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this question to the erlang-questions mailing list and received the following unfortunate answer:

> Hi!
>
> This is because of some software does not use the PKCS-standard oids
>   but alternative ISO-oids. In the upcoming version of public_key and
>   ssl this is solved by handling these alternative oids see commit:
>   006f45a738a6612958381b2fcbf48586c008d911
>
> Regards Ingela Erlang/OTP team - Ericsson AB

[Permalink to the response](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.general/67792)

Comment: Although I suppose its not so unfortunate because a fix is in the pipeline.